# SELECT SUM MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte consulta MYSQL:

```
select v.id,valor_sap,month(dthr_operacao) as mes, fornecedor_nome from viagem v                
INNER JOIN agente_viagem av ON v.id = av.viagem_id  
INNER JOIN agente ON av.agente_id = agente.agente_id  
INNER JOIN fornecedor on agente.fornecedor_id = fornecedor.fornecedor_id  
WHERE year(dthr_operacao) = 2015 and agente.fornecedor_id = 3 and month(dthr_operacao) = 2
```

Ela me retorna o seguinte:

```
id  |  valor  | mes  |  fornecedor
-----------------------------------
552 | 1439.10 |  2   | FORNECEDOR1  
552 | 1439.10 |  2   | FORNECEDOR1  
314 | 2331.07 |  2   | FORNECEDOR1  
643 | 1820.65 |  2   | FORNECEDOR1  
643 | 1820.65 |  2   | FORNECEDOR1
```

O que eu quero é a somatória do total, sem somar os IDs repetidos que no caso acima seria `5590,82`. Quando eu uso a instrução `MYSQL` acima com o `SUM(valor_sap)`, ele me retorna somando os IDS repetidos. Tentei usando `Group BY id` não dá certo, pois ele retorna tudo separado. Não posso usar `DISTINCT` no valor, pois existem outros registros com valores iguais.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer?

Comment: Não pode usar o `DISTINCT`, mas que outros valores iguais você quer mostrar?

Comment: Você só quer exibir o somatório final ou outras coisas?

Comment: Somente o somatório final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei exatamente qual o problema que você tem como o `DISTINCT`, mas é pra funcionar perfeitamente assim com um `SELECT` externo:

```
select SUM(t.valor_sap)  as total
FROM
(
    select DISTINCT v.id,valor_sap,month(dthr_operacao) as mes, fornecedor_nome from viagem v                
    INNER JOIN agente_viagem av ON v.id = av.viagem_id  
    INNER JOIN agente ON av.agente_id = agente.agente_id  
    INNER JOIN fornecedor on agente.fornecedor_id = fornecedor.fornecedor_id  
    WHERE year(dthr_operacao) = 2015 and agente.fornecedor_id = 3 and month(dthr_operacao) = 2
) t
```

Com o `DISTINCT` interno ele só retorna as linhas distintas, então retornaria 3 linhas conforme seu exemplo.

Comment: Maicon, obrigado pelo apoio. Na verdade eu não estava utilizando o DISTINCT porque talvez estava utilizando de forma errada, pois colocava loco no começo do SELECT. O meu problema é que eu estava fazendo um teste isolado e por isso respondi que queria só o valor. Na verdade eu preciso é da consulta do ano todo fazendo uma separação pelo fornecedor e pelo mês. O final da consulta é substituida pelo seguinte: WHERE year(dthr_operacao) = 2015
    GROUP BY fornecedor_nome, month(dthr_operacao).  Assim ele retorna o valor separado por fonecedor e por cada mês.

Comment: @Bruno meu exemplo funcionou para sua necessidade?